# GCC check if an expression will execute in a constant time

Tags: c, gcc

Let say I have the `(x << n) | (x >> (-n & 63))` expression.
There is nothing conditional in it.
So, to my understanding, it will be executed in constant time.

Indeed, when I compile the following code using `gcc -O3 -S`:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

// rotate left x by n places assuming n < 64
uint64_t rotl64(uint64_t x, uint8_t n) {
    return (x << n) | (x >> (-n & 63));
}
```

I get, on `linux/amd64`, the following output (which executes in constant time):

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4
    .globl  rotl64
    .type   rotl64, @function
rotl64:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movl    %esi, %ecx
    rolq    %cl, %rax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   rotl64, .-rotl64
    .ident  "GCC: (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

However, on `linux/386` I get an output that contains conditional jumps:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4
    .globl  rotl64
    .type   rotl64, @function
rotl64:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %edi
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 7, -8
    pushl   %esi
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 12
    .cfi_offset 6, -12
    movl    12(%esp), %eax
    movl    16(%esp), %edx
    movzbl  20(%esp), %ecx
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    %edx, %edi
    shldl   %esi, %edi
    sall    %cl, %esi
    testb   $32, %cl
    je  .L4
    movl    %esi, %edi
    xorl    %esi, %esi
.L4:
    negl    %ecx
    andl    $63, %ecx
    shrdl   %edx, %eax
    shrl    %cl, %edx
    testb   $32, %cl
    je  .L5
    movl    %edx, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
.L5:
    orl %esi, %eax
    orl %edi, %edx
    popl    %esi
    .cfi_restore 6
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    popl    %edi
    .cfi_restore 7
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   rotl64, .-rotl64
    .ident  "GCC: (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

From what I understand, here the 64 bits operations have to be emulated, hence the need of conditional jumps.

Does GCC provide a builtin function that indicates if an expression will be compiled with no jumps?
If it isn't the case, how can I know if an expression will be executed in constant time?
Is this a problem for timing sensitive applications like security?

Comment: The second one looks for me like compiled with -O0 flag. Enable optimizations and see again

Comment: The second one is compiled with -O3

Comment: clang compiles in `-m32` with no conditional jumps, but with `cmov`.

Comment: The information of instructions chosen may not exist at compile time when C++ is converted into an intermediate representation. At assembly generation time it can choose different instruction depending on the target cost model and optimization options.

Comment: OK but is there a way to ensure no conditional jumps when compiling unconditional expressions? By the way, the question is about C and GCC not C++ and Clang.

Comment: Do you mean "constant time" here in the sense of O(1), or literally constant (e.g. immune from side-channel timing attacks)?  Even code with no jumps won't necessarily execute in "constant time" in the latter sense, due to out-of-order execution, caching, etc.  Avoiding timing attacks usually requires careful handwritten assembly and it's unreasonable to expect it from compiled code.

Comment: I meant literally constant. Also, I didn't know that code with no jumps nor conditional moves were also vulnerable to timing attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does GCC provide a builtin function that indicates if an expression will be compiled with no jumps?

No.

> If it isn't the case, how can I know if an expression will be executed in constant time?

By looking at the generated assembly code.

> Is this a problem for timing sensitive applications like security?

Yes. That's why in these cases don't trust the compilers (and porters/package builders changing compiler settings) and rather implement it in assembly.

There are some constant time functions in general libc's, like in OpenBSD and FreeBSD. Like timingsafe_bcmp and timingsafe_memcmp, which are written in pure C, but their authors trust their packagers not to be like Debian or Ubuntu, who are assumed to break it.

Many other such functions are in the various security libraries itself, but even then you can safely assume that they are broken. For sure in OpenSSL and libsodium in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

No such a function does not exist.

And unless you are writing the compiler (you're not) you should not really care about the actual machine code being generated. The compiler is free to optimize that code anyway it sees fit (as long as it is correct) depending on the options you pass in. And with -O3 you should get the fastest code, even with jumps.

If there were a function like you suggested, you're code would be tied to a single version of a single compiler with a particular set of optimization options. In other words: bye bye portability.